# How to set the video orientation from landscape to portrait using CAAffineTranslation or any other way?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am merging the video using AVMutableComposition and the  videos gets merged.But the video gets stored in the landscape (which is default mode for AVAsset) after merging.So i want the video to be fix in portrait mode only...Is there any way to set the video orientation to portrait mode.
Thanx in advance

Here is the code i used for merging the video

```
NSArray *arrVideoUrl=[objApp.dictSelectedVideos allKeys];
NSMutableArray *arrVideoAsset=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<objApp.dictSelectedVideos.count; i++) {
      AVURLAsset *video=[[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[arrVideoUrl objectAtIndex:i] options:nil];
    [arrVideoAsset addObject:video];
}
AVURLAsset *music_track=[[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:songUrl options:nil];
//to mix up the media items
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
//Setting Audio track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
//setting the track to add the videos
AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVURLAsset *tempVideo1=[arrVideoAsset objectAtIndex:0];
AVURLAsset *tempVideo2=[arrVideoAsset objectAtIndex:1];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, tempVideo1.duration)ofTrack:[[tempVideo1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
if (arrVideoUrl.count==1)
{
    [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(kCMTimeZero, tempVideo2.duration))ofTrack:[[music_track tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
}
else{
        for (int j=1; j<=arrVideoAsset.count-1; j++)
     {
        AVURLAsset *tempVideoNext=[arrVideoAsset objectAtIndex:j];
        AVURLAsset *tempVideoPrev=[arrVideoAsset objectAtIndex:j-1];
        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, tempVideoNext.duration)ofTrack:[[tempVideoNext tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:tempVideoPrev.duration error:nil];

    }
    [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(tempVideo1.duration, tempVideo2.duration))ofTrack:[[music_track tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

}

Comment: were you able to come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Yes,add this line to the code ..
 [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:videoTrack.preferredTransform];
But this line will set the default orientation of the video, i.e if the video is in portrait..then it will be in potrait only and overcome the problem of orientation being changed due to default property of avexport session.

and if it is in landscape it will not converted to portrait ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution also ... if u want to change the orientation from landscape to portrait ... use this code

```
AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL  isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;

if(videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0)  {videoAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
if(videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0)  {videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
if(videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0)   {videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
if(videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}

CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0 / clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width;

if(isVideoAssetPortrait_) {
    FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height;
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [layerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}else{
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [layerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

//    [layerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];

```
AVAssetExportSession *assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];//AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;
```